# how to use sendAndConfirmRawTransaction with BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy, i need a demo

Tags: sendandconfirmrawtransaction, confirmationstrategy

new function:
/*

- Send and confirm a raw transaction
- 
- If `commitment` option is not specified, defaults to 'max' commitment.
- 
- @param {Connection} connection
- @param {Buffer} rawTransaction
- @param {BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy} confirmationStrategy
- @param {ConfirmOptions} [options]
- @returns {Promise}
  */
  export function sendAndConfirmRawTransaction(
  connection: Connection,
  rawTransaction: Buffer,
  confirmationStrategy: BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy,
  options?: ConfirmOptions,
  ): Promise;

old function:
/**

- @deprecated Calling `sendAndConfirmRawTransaction()` without a `confirmationStrategy`
- is no longer supported and will be removed in a future version.
  */
  export function sendAndConfirmRawTransaction(
  connection: Connection,
  rawTransaction: Buffer,
  options?: ConfirmOptions,
  ): Promise;

Answer (score 5):

You need the transaction signature when constructing the `BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy`, so you can't use `sendAndConfirmRawTransaction()` on your first go. You would use it if you roll your own retry logic instead of relying on `maxRetries`. I'm not sure if this will change in the future.

You can see the conversation that lead up to this new implementation in the GitHub issue, and they mention how they'll focus on `sendAndConfirmRawTransaction()` later: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/23949

Instead, you should send your raw transaction first, then confirm it like so:

```
const connection = new Connection("YOUR_RPC")
const tx = new Transaction()
const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(tx.serialize())

const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash()
const confirmStrategy: BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy = {
    blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature: signature
}
const result = await connection.confirmTransaction(confirmStrategy)
```

*note: the example is missing the instructions and signing of the tx*