# Using a confirmationStrategy to submit a serialized transaction

Tags: transactions, sendandconfirmrawtransaction, confirmationstrategy

We are taking a signed and serialized transaction and trying to call `sendAndConfirmRawTransaction` with a `confirmationStrategy`.

The issue I am running into is that the `lastValidBlockHeight` on the transaction is `undefined` because the `serialize` logic doesn't include it in the serialized payload.

Is it safe to call `getLatestBlockhash` and use the `lastValidBlockHeight` from the response in the `confirmationStrategy`?

Does the `blockhash` used in the `confirmationStrategy` need to match the `recentBlockhash` that the transaction was created with?

```
const transaction = Transaction.from(Buffer.from(serialized, 'base64'));
const { lastValidBlockHeight, signature, recentBlockhash } = transaction;

const confirmationStrategy = {
  lastValidBlockHeight,
  signature: bs58.encode(signature),
  blockhash: recentBlockhash,
};
```

Comment: Does the answer here help? https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1426/how-to-use-sendandconfirmrawtransaction-with-blockheightbasedtransactionconfirma

Comment: @CallumM Yeah I just saw that right after I posted my question. However still wondering about the following: Does the `blockhash` used in the `confirmationStrategy` need to match the `recentBlockhash` that the transaction was created with?