# How to add confirmationStrategy in JS

Tags: web3.js, confirmationstrategy, js

Hello I already read this [question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1426/how-to-use-sendandconfirmrawtransaction-with-blockheightbasedtransactionconfirma)

But I don't know how to create the BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy object in JS as in that example TS is used.

I will like to get this code in JS:

```
const connection = new Connection("YOUR_RPC")
const tx = new Transaction()
const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(tx.serialize())

const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash()
const confirmStrategy: BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy = {
    blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature: signature
}
const result = await connection.confirmTransaction(confirmStrategy)
```

EDIT 1:

I tried:

```
  const sig = conn.sendRawTransaction(tx.serialize())
  console.log(sig);
  const latestBlockHash = conn.getLatestBlockhash();
  const txConfirmation = conn.confirmTransaction({
        blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
        signature: sig,
  });
```

But got this error:

```
throw new Error('signature must be base58 encoded: ' + rawSignature);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting the `await` keywords as they're used in the example you're borrowing from. Failing to include them will make Javascript return a `promise` rather than waiting to receive the actual value you'd expect the function to return.